# Is there a method to log the raw XML returned from a SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am maintaining a legacy application which displays a transient error in certain circumstances the first time a series of queries are executed.

The application uses SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader which returns an XmlReader object. This contains invalid XML when the error occurs, and the application throws an exception.

Try as I might I cannot find a way to view the raw XML of the output before it is passed to a method which creates a new XPathDocument from it. Anything I do to the XmlReader object (such as trying to log its inner contents) causes the reader to be unusable by any further code.

I am looking for some way to be able to simply log all the raw XML coming from the command so that when the error occurs I can see the exact XML that lead to the error, helping me to narrow down my search.

I have tried cloning the XmlReader, but the results from SQL contain multiple result sets (it's a stored proc with multiple return statements). Converting the result to string using a stringbuilder and then trying to convert that string back to an XmlReader results in an exception because there a multiple root nodes.

Is there any straightforward solution to this?

```
//execute the command
var xmlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
var xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlReader); //<--exception thrown here
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is something like:

```
var xmlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
LogXmlResults(xmlReader);
var xpathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlReader);
```

Comment: Post the exception. Also, I think you just has a bug in the string/xml conversion. Maybe you appended multiple result sets to the same string?

Comment: The exception is hexadecimal character x is invalid. But the character can change between errors. They quite often appear as Chinese characters. Can post specific exception when back to my dev pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has invalid characters. For some reason XML is defined to not allow certain characters even in encoded form. This never made sense to me.

The solution seems to be that you need to create the `XmlReader` yourself and set the `CheckCharacters` option to `false`.

So you need to obtain a `TextReader` from ADO.NET and create an `XmlReader` from it. I would use `SqlDataReader.GetTextReader` for that.

Comment: Thanks @usr - this definitely pointed me in the right direction. I ended up calling `sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` then looping through the results (the stored proc returns multiple record sets) and appending the result to a stringbuilder. I then created a new `XmlReader` as you suggested with `CheckCharacters` set to `false` and `ConformanceLevel` set to `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`. Haven't seen the issue since.